# Unlocking a locked user whose password limit has exceeded in Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a use case where i have to lock the user after unsuccessful attempts of username and password and then later the admin should be able to unlock the user in Cognito and then the user should be able to login .

For now Cognito locks the user after 5 unsuccessful attempts of username and password and when the user tries to login with a proper username and password it gives the following exception.
"Unable to login because of security reasons. "
However i'm not able to find a way to unlock that particular user as an admin.Does Cognito provide any API or dashboard for unlocking the user?. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot interfere with their default lockout policy. You can however put in your own logic to lock out users using pre sign in lambda trigger along with custom field which stores recent unsuccessful login attempts. Lambda is triggered and checks if user has too many login attempts and then blocks him from logging in.

You can then write another function that lets admin clear the custom field that tracks unsuccessful logins.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. If I keep a custom field & then reset the field, the lockout policy is still in effect. So even though the custom field says I can try to login again, Cognito will throw an error for too many failed attempts until Cognito's lockout time is reached.

Comment: If you block the request from going forward, it shouldn't trigger cognito's auto blocking. Have you tried this?

Comment: Lets say you have the pre-sign in lambda trigger & save the unsuccessful login attempts in a custom field. Now lets say the user fails login 5 times in a row. So our system says the user has 5 login attempts, & Cognito's internal system also says they have 5 login attempts.

Now lets say the user tries to sign in 1 more time, & we block it to avoid Cognito's lockout policy. If an admin clears the custom field that tracks unsuccessful login attempts, our system will let them login again, but Cognito will not, because Cognito still has those initial 5 failed login attempts for the user.

Comment: You're right, if you do this it has to have a tighter limit than cognito. This is why I started with "you can't change the default lockout behavior". It's only useful if you think cognito is too generous with their lockout policy!

Answer (score -1):

if you make a call to disable the user, then re-enable the user, that resets the login attempts and your user should be able to log in

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me. After disabling and reenabling the user, they continue to be marked as High risk.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work for me either... And not even if I reset the user password by admin. Any other workaround or API to do that?